# MongoDB backup as text rather than binary for source control

Tags: git, mongodb, version-control, automation

Is it possible to do this?

The reason I ask is that it would seem useful to perform a backup as a pre-commit hook, and include that text-based backup somehow with the code being committed, such that every revision in source control (git) has the necessary backups associated with it.

I realise that it may be possible to get MongoDB to spit out all it's collections as JSON, and back them up that way, but then this would not contain DB and collection metadata.

**The central concern** is that when branching to make changes to server side code, then reverting that branch, it is easy for us to forget to make the necessary backups that will allow an effective revert (code will no longer match schema). One could claim this is programmer error, but I think there should be some automation in place to ensure that we have a version of the database that is current for every version of the code. This is the problem with schemas that are amorphous during the early days of a project... dynamic schemas being Mongo's main blessing and curse.

Comment: @Calimero Nothing. I'm asking for advice before I start wasting time going down beaten paths that lead nowhere, as this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Backing up the full database prior to every code commit sounds like an extreme requirement. It would be more typical to backup a database prior to a deploy rather than as a pre-commit hook. Are you only trying to backup the collection/index definitions, or the full data as well? MongoDB stores its data in a [BSON (Binary JSON) format](http://bsonspec.org/) so if you are converting to a text-only format you should be aware of potential [data type fidelity](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/#data-type-fidelity) issues. I wouldn't recommend bloating your git repo with DB backups.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks for your input. The central concern is that when branching to make changes to server side code, then reverting that branch, it is easy for us to forget to make the necessary backups that will allow an effective revert (code will no longer match schema). One could claim this is programmer error, but I think there should be some automation in place to ensure that we have a version of the database that is current for every version of the code. This is the problem with schemas that are amorphous during the early days of a project... this being Mongo's main blessing and curse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB stores its data in a [BSON (Binary JSON) format](http://bsonspec.org/) so if you are converting to a text-only format you should be aware of potential [data type fidelity](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/#data-type-fidelity) issues. If you want a consistent backup of your MongoDB database, the recommended format would be the binary output of [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/back-up-and-restore-with-mongodb-tools/#backup-a-database-with-mongodump).  I wouldn't recommend bloating your git repo with binary DB backups, though.

Typically one of the liberating aspects of a database with schema flexibility is *not* having to worry about schema migrations during development.  This does require some consideration on how your application will handle varying schema versions, so having a more controlled approach is fine, too.

Since your main goal is to keep your database schema in sync with code changes, a much better approach would be to investigate schema migration tools.  These typically allow you to create upgrade/downgrade code snippets with a defined order of application to a database,  and ensure that any changes to the database schema that aren't handled by your application code *are* captured in the migration scripts.

Some example tools:

- [mongo-migrate (NodeJS)](https://npmjs.org/package/mongo-migrate)
- [Mongeez (Java)](https://github.com/secondmarket/mongeez)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how this actually works. I'm not sure I'm grasping the core concept of this migration tool. What do you mean by "defined order of application", could this be compared to applying patches incrementally in order to shift up and down the version "ladder", so to speak? So in order to use this, we would, what, check out current version code, then apply several patches to it in order to get it back to say the last tagged API version, then refresh the DB with backups from that tag, and everything should work?

Comment: @NickWiggill: Yes, think you've got the concept. Migrations usually need to be applied in some defined order so they can be transitions between known database states (aka up/down the version ladder). There is usually one command to run to sync your schema from whatever the current state is to the desired one.