# Collaborative MongoDB development through GIT?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, github

A few of my co-workers and I have decided to dive into Ruby but none of us have much experience with it. We are using a LocomotiveCMS installation which uses Mongo to store database entries.

We are having some troubles figuring out how best to work collaboratively on this project. Currently I am running the mongodump command which generates a series of json/bson files and then I compress those files, push them through GIT, my co-workers pull the compressed file, extract the bson/jfiles and then use mongorestore to get the most current DB running on their local installation.

Is there an easier way than this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can try an online service like Mongolab or MongoHQ in order to share the same database. Those services has free plans that fits perfectly for develop an application over MongoDB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB backup as text rather than binary for source control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814866) which was recently asked. If you want a local development database with consistent change history, schema migrations are a useful approach so your local test data doesn't get overwritten. If you are more worried about keeping in sync with test data, a hosted or shared MongoDB instance (as suggested by @rubenfa) is a probably an easier approach than pushing binary dumps through Git. Another option is to share the backups with your team using a service like Dropbox.